# how to print only values from database by avoiding row name and so ( in Django)

Tags: python, mysql, django

am using Django and database is mysql , when am printing id from row its  printing `{ id: 45 }` , but I only need result `45`...someone can help?

```
itemList = todoitem.objects.filter(content__in=wordlist).values("id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [**`values_list(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) with `flat=True` as parameter:

```
itemList = todoitem.objects.filter(
    content__in=wordlist
).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Note that this is *not* a list, it is a `QuerySet`. The items in the queryset are however `int`s here, not dictionaries, nor lists.

Comment: its showing  the error  "NameError: name 'true' is not defined" ...I need a code which support text value also

Comment: @merakiclt: you wrote `true` instead of `True` (with an uppercase).